# What does disable Campaign Influence actually do?

Tags: campaign, campaign-influence

According to the message on the page where you disable it:

"Users must designate influential campaigns using the related list on the opportunity"

What actually seems to happen is this.

When Campaign Influence is enabled, and you convert a lead, it creates a Campaign Influence on the Opportunity for EVERY Campaign the Lead is a member of.

When Campaign Influence is disabled, and you convert a lead, it creates a Campaign Influence on the Opportunity for just ONE of the Campaigns the Lead is a member of.

Is this working as designed, or a SFDC bug?

Answer (score 1):

See [this help topic](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=campaigns_influence_using.htm&siteLang=en_US):

> The campaign you designate as the primary campaign source will always appear in the Campaign Influence related list.

The latest campaign for the lead becomes the opportunity's *primary campaign*, which is used for reporting purposes (ROI, total new business, etc). As such, it also appears on the Campaign Influence list, regardless of if the automatic association feature is enabled.

Comment: #sfdcfox @sfdcfox
There is a requirement from a client that is adding a contact role on opportunity after it's close date has been passed.
As per documentation of Campaign influence opportunity report, it shows data for contact roles that are added prior to the close date.

Any workaround possible against this.

Comment: @VivekMakkar You'll want to add a new question regarding this. Comments are not intended for new questions.